# How we can use container_name as log_stream_name (or) log_stream_prefix in fluentbit cloudwatch output

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, fluent-bit

Here iam trying to get container_name from kubernates dict and i want to use it as log_stream_name

[FILTER]
Name                nest
Match               application.*
Operation           lift
Nested_under        kubernetes
Add_prefix          Nested.

```
[FILTER]
    Name                modify
    Match               application.*
    Rename              Nested.docker_id            Docker.container_id

[FILTER]
    Name                nest
    Match               application.*
    Operation           nest
    Wildcard            Nested.*
    Nested_under        kubernetes
    Remove_prefix       Nested.

[FILTER]
    Name                nest
    Match               application.*
    Operation           nest
    Wildcard            Docker.*
    Nested_under        docker
    Remove_prefix       Docker.
```

[OUTPUT]
Name                cloudwatch_logs
Match               application.*
region              ${REGION}
log_group_name      /aws/containerinsights/${CLUSTER_NAME}/application
log_stream_name     $(kubernetes['container_name'])
auto_create_group   true
extra_user_agent    container-insights